# How do I make multiple buffers use a single sql connection?

Tags: sql-interactive-mode, sql, sql-mode

I am using sql mode. Is there a way to connect multiple buffers to a single sql connection? When I try to connect an existing buffer to a database, it always creates a new connection instead of reusing the existing one.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sql-set-sqli-buffer-generally` command can be used to make all the buffers use the latest connection created. For a related question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5431463/1589512